# Avoid footnotes from appearing before mark

Tags: positioning, footnotes

I have these `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark` as illustrated in the figure below. I used these tags to enforce my own numbering (and because using only `\footnote` was not working the way I expected).

[image: My footnotetext/footnotemark as they are rendering]

The code I use for generating the mark is:

```
 \caption{Lista de notas presentes em um piano de 88 teclas,
 com notação em Inglês, frequência em Hertz e comprimento de
 onda em centímetros.\protect\footnotemark[1]}
```

Is there any way I can enforce my `\footnotetext` to appear in the same page as my `\footnotemark`?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the observation that "using only `\footnote` was not working the way I expected". Was it the matter that you are trying to place a footnote marker inside a `table` environment? Are you using any specific placement directives -- such as `[t]` or `[t!]` -- to influence the placement of the float?

Comment: @Mico I tried using `\footnote`, but then the footnote mark showed and my actual footnote text wasn't placed anywhere in the text. I'm putting these inside a `table` environment, and I suspect it may have something to do with my problem.

Comment: latex doesn't really support page footnotes out of a floating environment. You can use a minipage so the footnote text comes at the bottom of the float. If you want a page footnote and the float floats to `t` or `b` you can add the `\footnotetext` by hand on the correct page. If the float floats to a `p` float page, it is not possible to add the footnote text without major modifications to the latex output routine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you have a tutorial for this "minipage" stuff?

Comment: not really, other than any latex tutorial but `\begin{figure}\begin{minpage}{\linewidth}...... \footnote{xxxx}... \end{minipage}{\end{figure}` is all I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much detail about how the floats are being positioned, so I can't comment on that aspect of your document creation process.

Instead, I'd like to suggest you consider using the [threeparttable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) environment (provided by a package with the same name), which can be included inside a `table` environment. The three parts are the caption, the `tabular` (or `tabularx`, `tabular*`, `tabulary`, etc.) environment that contains the actual table, and the `tablenotes` environment that contains the footnotes referenced via footnote marks in the caption and tabular environments. Note that the tablenotes will be printed at the end of the `table` environment rather than at the bottom of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttable,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Lista de notas presentes em um piano de 88 teclas,
 com notação em Inglês, frequência em Hertz e comprimento de
 onda em centímetros.\tnote{a}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X||X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  N & N & F & C & N & N & F & C\\
  \hline
  1 & &&& 2 &&&\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Adaptado de \dots
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The main advantage of using the `threeparttable` environment rather than, say, a dedicated `minipage` environment is the much greater flexibility in the numbering and the appearance of the footnote marks: They can be numeric, alphabetic, symbolic, or anything else you can think of.